# Is it possible to open an IHP shell?

Tags: ihp

Maybe a dumb question if there is an obvious answer, but is there a way to open up your IHP project in something like ghci to be able to, e.g., run queries from the database and such interactively through Haskell? Obviously you could do this through SQL itself but IHP/Haskell is nicer for basic queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to open ghci with:

```
nix-shell
ghci
```

Comment: `make console` also gets you into ghci and is a bit faster to load :)